# after installation, not able to login in knowage (http://localhost:8080/knowage)

Tags: spagobi, fiware-knowage

I am done with knowage CE6.2 installation just now. And when I am trying to login using user -
demo_admin(user name and password are same)
demo_user (user name and password are same)
I am unable to log in .

Please see the attachment , That shows the default user while installation process

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need start the server of knowage located in the windows button.

Hope give you some help

best resguards